# Search results missing for web application for external connections

Tags: 2010, search, search-results

We have SharePoint exposed externally via ForeFront TMG.  The SSL connection terminates at TMG and is then proxyed internally over HTTP.
Our "hosted" application is accessed internally by http://hosted.corp.com and the same app externally is accessed by https://hosted.corp.com. Internally all results show up fine, but externally we get no results.
Our other web applications which are crawled by the same service work fine internally and externally.

Comment: Hi Ryan, our scenario is same as yours. Did you got any solution for this...Thanks

Comment: I don't remember, I haven't done any SharePoint since early 2014. Sorry